# Dynamic query in couchbase?

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I started using couchbase,
i like it a lot but one thing i cant find,
making a dynamic query,

```
{
    "sender_name": "roman",
    "sender_id": 123,
    "content": "Hello World"
}
```

Now i want to query for document where "sender_id" = ?.

It can be any number,
Regular view with doc and meta cant help me because i dont know the value,
I should expect any sender_id.

Hope you can help me, thanks alot.

Comment: Since CouchBase doesn't support ad-hoc queries, but requires you to have views, I guees you are talking about "how you can make your view dynamic". If the field in turn can be whatever "simple" data type, can't you control the format of it or a surrogate field that you turn into a string?

Comment: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-sql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , with Couchbase you can write Map&Reduce functions, and create views. The map functions accept parameters. I am not quite familiar with writing a Map function, but from couchbase.com  I think this map function will do your job.

```
 function(doc, meta) 
 {
    emit(doc.sender_id, [doc.content]);
 }
```

And your query would be ?key=["123"]

Go through these links

1. http://hardlifeofapo.com/creating-an-e-commerce-platform-using-couchbase-2/
2. http://hardlifeofapo.com/basic-couchbase-querying-for-sql-people/
3. http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-sql-where.html

Comment: Note that you can also create the view from your code as documented here http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.fr/2012/12/couchbase-101-create-views-mapreduce.html  ( in java but you can do it from other programming languages too)